# How to automatically add a value to an existing value in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

How can I run this SQL statement with Laravel Eloquent ORM using my model?

```
update products set quantity = quantity + 3
```

Comment: Take note of [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: Read the docs, please: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#running-queries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to get specific instace to change:

`$product = Product::find($id);`

Now, you have all attributes of object and can change loaded values:

`$product->quantity += 3;`

Finally, you must to save changes:

`$product->save();`

Then, if you check your database the value will be changed.

Ps.: using Eloquent.

Comment: It's probably better to use `$product->increment('quantity', 3)` here. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#increment-and-decrement